# Having problems installing external modules in Odoo 16.0

Tags: odoo

When I transfer the external module through FTP to the Odoo Addons folder, Odoo does not recognize the external modules. How can I solve this problem?

recognize the external modules

Answer (score 1):

First: if you are using custom folder for your external modules, you need to add it's path to the `addons_path` in **Odoo Config file**.

To be able to see the module in Odoo,You need to **restart the Odoo service** and then Go to **Apps** then click on **Update Apps List** menu.